# Inequality for normalized weights

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\{w_{i,k}\}_{(i,k) \in [1:N]^2}$ be some positive real numbers such that $\sum_{i = 1}^N w_{i,k} = 1$.
I have conjectured that $\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j,k \in [1:N]^2} w_{i,j} w_{i,k} = \mathcal{O}(N)$ but i am unable to prove it. Is there such an inequality?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. If you try $w_{1,k}\to1$ for all $k$ and others are close to zero, $\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j,k \in [1:N]^2} w_{i,j} w_{i,k}=N^2$. However, $N^2$ is the largest possible value it can take if you allow zero.

Comment: Indeed. thank you